# Facebook.addJSEventListener callback function not being called

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a facebook application with the help of Facebook graph API in Actionscript3. For some weird reason 2 days ago **Facebook.addJSEventListener** decided not to call the callback function anymore.

Here is my code:

```
    static public function ConnectToApp(sAppID_:String , sPermissions_:String, sRedirectURL_:String):void
    {
        sAppID = sAppID_;
        sPermissions = sPermissions_;
        sRedirectURL = sRedirectURL_;
        Facebook.init(sAppID, loginHandler);
    }

    static private function loginHandler(objectSession_:Object,objectFail_:Object):void
    {
        if( objectSession_ == null)
        {
            ExternalInterface.call("redirect",sAppID, sPermissions,sRedirectURL);
        }

        Facebook.addJSEventListener('auth.statusChange', detectLogin);
    }

    static private function detectLogin(userInfo_:Object):void
    {
        if (userInfo_.status == "connected")
        {
            iUserStatus = Globals.FB_USER_CONNECTED;
            iUserID = userInfo_.authResponse.userID;
            Facebook.api('/me' ,getMeHandler);
            Security.loadPolicyFile("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
            sProfilePicURL = Facebook.getImageUrl(iUserID.toString());
            loadMyPicture();
        }
        else if (userInfo_.status == "not_authorized")
        {
            iUserStatus = Globals.FB_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED;
        }
        else
        {
            iUserStatus = Globals.FB_USER_NOT_CONNECTED;
        }
    }
```

**Facebook.init** is calling the loginHandler callback function but **Facebook.addJSEventListener('auth.statusChange', detectLogin);**  decides not to.

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work. I did the following code change:

```
    static public function ConnectToApp(sAppID_:String , sPermissions_:String, sRedirectURL_:String):void
    {
        sAppID = sAppID_;
        sPermissions = sPermissions_;
        sRedirectURL = sRedirectURL_;
        Facebook.init(sAppID, loginHandler);
    }

    static private function loginHandler(objectSession_:Object,objectFail_:Object):void
    {
        if( objectSession_ == null)
        {
            ExternalInterface.call("redirect",sAppID, sPermissions,sRedirectURL);
            return;
        }

        GetAllInfo();
    }

    static private function GetAllInfo():void
    {
        iUserStatus = Globals.FB_USER_CONNECTED;
        iUserID = int(Facebook.getAuthResponse().uid);
        Facebook.api('/me' ,getMeHandler);
        Security.loadPolicyFile("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
        sProfilePicURL = Facebook.getImageUrl(iUserID.toString());
        loadMyPicture();
    }
```

So basically now I'm not adding an event listener that calls a callback function when the user is connected, if the session is not ready I redirect and return... when the session is ready I automatically start getting the information.

I am not sure if I will ever get a problem where I start asking for the info before fully logging in but so far I did a lot of tests and it seems to work.

If anyone has a better solution please let me know.